# rvalues and temporary objects in the FCD

Tags: c++, c++11, temporary, rvalue

It took me quite some time to understand the difference between an rvalue and a temporary object. But now the final committee draft states on page 75:

> An *rvalue* [...] **is** an xvalue, **a temporary object** or subobject thereof, or a value that is not associated with an object.

I can't believe my eyes. This must be an error, right?

---

To clarify, here is how I understand the terms:

```
#include <string>

void foo(std::string&& str)
{
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    foo(std::string("hello"));
}
```

In this program, there are two *expressions* that denote the same *temporary object*: the prvalue `std::string("hello")` and the lvalue `str`. Expressions are not objects, but their evaluation might yield one. Specifically, the evaluation of a prvalue yields a temporary object, but a prvalue IS NOT a temporary object. Does anyone agree with me or have I gone insane? :)

Comment: You might consider asking the standards people directly by posting a question to comp.lang.c++.std

Comment: @Noah: I did. Let's see what happens :)

Comment: [link to comp.std.c++ thread](http://groups.google.de/group/comp.std.c++/browse_thread/thread/5cdae718218a462c)

Comment: I have forgotten where I saw it, but someone from the C++ committee had posted a photo of a whiteboard showing "the new expression type hierarchy;" the next day he posted another similar but different photo with the caption "well, that didn't last long" (now I'm irritated because I can't remember who it was!)  Clearly this is a somewhat contentious issue.

Comment: "_Does anyone agree with me or have I gone insane? :)_" Someone went insane, and that someone is not you. ;)

Comment: An expression does not denote a temporary object.  It denotes a series of operations, which yield an object.  That object is the result of evaluating the expression, but separate from the expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, i agree with you. This should be fixed in my opinion, and several people i deeply pay respect to have risen the exact same question about this.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't as complicated as it sounds. I am referring to the now finalized standard ISO/IEC 14882-2011. Page 78 says:

> An xvalue (an “eXpiring” value) also refers to an object, usually near
>   the end of its lifetime (so that its resources may be moved, for
>   example). **An xvalue is the result of certain kinds of expressions
>   involving rvalue references** (8.3.2).

The bold above has been added by me. The standard further says:

> An rvalue (so called, historically, because rvalues could appear on
>   the right-hand side of an assignment expression) is an xvalue, a
>   temporary object (12.2) or subobject thereof, or a value that is not
>   associated with an object.

So you only get an xvalue when you are playing around with 'certain kinds of expressions involving rvalue references'. Otherwise your temporary objects are just that - temporary objects.

Comment: Removed embedded question. Ask it as another question.