# printing a member of a returned struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct, return-value, lvalue

I'm having trouble printing a member of a struct that is returned from a function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct hex_string
{
    char a[9];
};

struct hex_string to_hex_string_(unsigned x)
{
    static const char hex_digits[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    struct hex_string result;
    char * p = result.a;
    int i;
    for (i = 28; i >= 0; i -= 4)
    {
        *p++ = hex_digits[(x >> i) & 15];
    }
    *p = 0;
    printf("%s\n", result.a);   /* works */
    return result;
}

void test_hex(void)
{
    printf("%s\n", to_hex_string_(12345).a);   /* crashes */
}
```

The `printf` call inside `to_hex_string_` prints the correct result, but the `printf` call inside `test_hex` crashes my program. Why exactly is that? Is it a lifetime issue, or is it something else?

When I replace the `printf` call with `puts(to_hex_string_(12345).a)`, I get a compiler error:

```
invalid use of non-lvalue array
```

What's going on here?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: That's one possible symptom of undefined behavior.

Comment: Do you have `#include <stdio.h>` at the top of your source file?  And why the trailing underscore on the function name?  (It's legal, but odd.)

Comment: @KeithThompson: Yes, `stdio.h` is included. Trailing underscores are my personal convention for throwaway toy functions if I already have a stable function with the same name.

Comment: I've added `#include <stdio.h>` to the question.  There are cases (not this one) where a missing `#include` directive could be the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a rule in C which seldom comes into effect, which states:

> If an attempt is made to modify the result of a function call or to
>   access it after the next sequence point, the behavior is undefined. <sub>(C99 §6.5.2.2)</sub>

In this case, there is a sequence point after the arguments to `printf()` are evaluated and before the `printf()` function itself executes.  The pointer you pass to `printf()` is a pointer *to an element of the return value itself* - and when `printf()` tries to access the string through that pointer, you get your crash.

This issue is hard to run into, because a function value isn't an lvalue so you can't directly take a pointer to it with `&`.

Comment: So how come the `printf` call crashes, whereas the `puts` call fails to compile?

Comment: @FredOverflow: The difference in gcc behaviour appears to be a result of the function prototype for `puts()` (you get the same warning if you try an assignment like `char *x = to_hex_string(1).a`).  I believe it to be a bug, because the undefined behaviour only kicks in once the array is accessed through that pointer value; merely copying the pointer value does not seem to contradict any constraint.  It is probably not an important one, though.

Comment: I note also that the gcc warning disappears if you use `&to_hex_string(1).a[0]`, underscoring the fragility surrounding that warning.

Comment: I'm curious: I can't find those words in C99 §6.5.2.2 in the original version of the standard, nor in any of the 3 technical corrigenda.  It also doesn't exist in the C11 standard in section §6.5.2.2.

Comment: In C11, §6.2.4 ¶8 says _A non-lvalue expression with structure or union type, where the structure or union
contains a member with array type (including, recursively, members of all contained
structures and unions) refers to an object with automatic storage duration and temporary
lifetime.36) Its lifetime begins when the expression is evaluated and its initial value is the
value of the expression. Its lifetime ends when the evaluation of the containing full
expression or full declarator ends. Any attempt to modify an object with temporary
lifetime results in undefined behavior._

Comment: The equivalent words don't exist in the corresponding section of C99 (also §6.2.4 — there is no ¶8 though).  I may still just have missed them.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: It's the last sentence of §6.5.2.2 ¶5 in C99 TC3.

Comment: Ah, found it — it was present in ¶5 in the original standard, too.  I'm not sure how I missed it.  The rules in C11 are somewhat different, it would seem — that sentence seems to be missing from §6.5.2.2, and the nearest I've found is §6.2.4 ¶8, already quoted.

Comment: Yes, one of the changes in C11 was to introduce objects of temporary lifetime.  The question is only really applicable to pre-C11 environments I think.

Answer (score 13):

You've managed to run into a fairly obscure corner case of the language.

An expression of array type, in most contexts, is implicitly converted to a pointer to the first element of the array; the exceptions are when the expression is the operand of a unary `&` operator, when it's the operand of a unary `sizeof` operator, and when it's a string literal in an initializer used to initialize an array object.  None of these exceptions applies here.

But there's an implicit assumption in that conversion: the pointer is to the first element of the array *object*.

Most array expressions -- almost all of them, in fact -- refer to some array object, such as a declared array variable, an element of a multidimensional array, and so forth.  Functions can't return arrays, so you can't get a non-lvalue array expression that way.

But as you've seen, a function can return a struct that contains an array -- and there's no object associated with the array expression `to_hex_string_(12345).a`.

The new ISO C11 standard addresses this by adding new wording to the section describing storage durations.  [The N1570 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), section 6.2.4p8, says:

> A non-lvalue expression with structure or union type, where the
>   structure or union contains a member with array type (including,
>   recursively, members of all contained structures and unions) refers to
>   an object with automatic storage duration and *temporary lifetime*.
>   Its lifetime begins when the expression is evaluated and its initial
>   value is the value of the expression. Its lifetime ends when the
>   evaluation of the containing full expression or full declarator ends.
>   Any attempt to modify an object with temporary lifetime results in
>   undefined behavior.

In effect, this says that the returned value from your function (unlike most function results) is the value of a temporary *object*, allowing the decay of its array member to give you a (temporarily) valid pointer.

But until compilers fully support the new C standard (which won't be for some years), you'll just have to avoid referring to array members of returned structures.

Comment: Aha, so C doesn't have C++'s notion of temporary objects (yet). Interesting choice to make them "const", that isn't the case in C++.

Comment: So how come the `printf` call crashes, whereas the `puts` call fails to compile?

Comment: @FredOverflow: It may well be a gcc bug.  Using gcc 4.5.2, I get a warning on the `printf` call: `warning: format ‘%s’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char[9]’` (so apparently it's not doing the usual array-to-pointer conversion).  On the `puts` call, I get `error: invalid use of non-lvalue array`, as you did.  I can't think of any good reason for them to behave *that* differently.  But the behavior is undefined, so you should just avoid doing that.

Comment: @FredOverflow: It's not actually "const".  Attempting to modify it has undefined behavior, but it's not `const`-qualified.  It's similar to C's treatment of string literals.

Answer (score -1):

The problem you're facing is that : the variable `result` which is return is a local variable of the function **_to_hex_string**, that's means it is deleted at the end of the fonction call. so when you try to check it in the fonction `test_hex` it is no available any more.

To solve your problem you can deal with pointer.

here is your code modify

```
struct hex_string
{
    char a[9];
};

struct hex_string * to_hex_string_(unsigned x) // here you return a pointer
{
    static const char hex_digits[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    struct hex_string result;

    result = (struct hex_string *) malloc(sizeof(struct hex_string));
    char * p = result->a;
    int i;

    for (i = 28; i >= 0; i -= 4)
    {
        *p++ = hex_digits[(x >> i) & 15];
    }

    *p = 0;
    printf("%s\n", result->a);   /* works */
    return result;
}

void test_hex(void)
{
    printf("%s\n", to_hex_string_(12345)->a);  /* works */
}
```

Have I nice day

Comment: You `malloc`, but you never `free`. That's a memory leak.