# Need some help on r-value concept

Tags: c++, c++11, lvalue, rvalue

When I try compiling following program, I get an error on l-value which makes sense. 
Error is: error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value

Code:

```
int main() 
{
    int a,b,c,d;
    b+c=d;
    return 0;
 }
```

But following code works absolutely fine when I replace integer with my own structure

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int val;
    MyStruct(){}
};

MyStruct operator+(MyStruct& s1, MyStruct& s2)
{
    MyStruct temp;
    return temp;
}

int main() 
{

    MyStruct a,b,c,d;
    b+c=d;
    return 0;
}
```

How come the second code compiles?
I know I can return const from the operator+. But isn't b+c in second example a rvalue? So how come it compiles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Cory Klein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/446554/cory-klein) has already explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17752883/1137388) why the code compiles.

I just want to add that if you want `MyStruct` to behave as the `int`s (and othe built-in types), then add this line to `MyStruct`:

```
MyStruct& operator =(const MyStruct&) && = delete;
```

This tells the compiler that that everytime the `operator =()` is called on a `MyStruct` object that is an rvalue (thanks to the *ref-qualifier* `&&`) the code should not be valid because the `operator =()` does not exist (`= delete;`). Indeed, GCC 4.8.1 emmits the following:

> > error: use of deleted function 'MyStruct& MyStruct::operator=(const MyStruct&) &&'
> >
> > ```
> > b+c=d;
> >    ^
> > ```

**Update**: Following the comment by [Casey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/923854/casey) (many thanks).

There's one issue with adding the line above to `MyStruct`. It also prevents assignment to an lvalue. That is, the line below also becomes illegal:

```
b = c;
```

If you want to disable assignment to an rvalue but still allows assignment to lvalues, then instead of the line above, add this one to `MyStruct`:

```
MyStruct& operator =(const MyStruct&) & = default;
```

(or provide a correct implementation if the compiler generated one doesn't fit your purposes.)

Comment: I've been using `MyStruct& operator = (const MyStruct&) & = default;` to accomplish the same end. Can you think of any reason to favor deleting over defaulting?

Comment: @Casey: I didn't know that this would do the same. Actually your solution is superior to mine and I will update my answer. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 1):

In this code:

```
MyStruct a,b,c,d;
b+c=d;
```

As you have defined the `operator+()` function, it returns a `MyStruct`. Therefore `b+c`, which calls the function you defined, returns a `MyStruct`, and then the `operator=()` function is called on that `MyStruct`, and it is passed `d` as an argument.

Although the temporary `MyStruct` [is an rvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11237362/446554) because of its temporary nature, the code still compiles because of the reasons I explained above, and the fact that the C++ standard does not forbid calling the `operator=()` function on an rvalue when that rvalue is a user defined object and not an integral type.

In this code:

```
int a,b,c,d;
b+c=d;
```

`b+c` returns an r-value int. Having an r-value on the left side of an `=` operator is not C++ syntax. Either way, it wouldn't make any sense to assign a value to it, whereas calling the `operator=()` function on a temporary `MyStruct` could potentially have side effects.

Comment: If it is not C++ syntax, then howcome it compiles? Instead If I write (b+c).val = d.val this one fails

Comment: It does not compile, you say so yourself - it gets error code C2106. The `MyStruct` code *is* proper C++ syntax, therefore it compiles.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I guess my basic query is why temporary Mystruct is not a r-value

Comment: @Cory Klein: "That temporary MyStruct is not an r-value.". Actually, the temporary is an rvalue. The issue is that rvalues of class type don't behave like rvalues of bult-in types (as you have clearly explained).

Comment: I've updated the answer with an explanation on why `MyStruct` is not an rvalue.

Comment: @CassioNeri I don't doubt that what you say is true, but it does conflict with the definition in the referenced link I just added to the answer. Can you provide some point of reference to show that the temporary `MyStruct` is in fact an r-value?

Comment: Okay, I've added another reference defining the `MyStruct` as an lvalue. Now I am beginning to doubt you @CassioNeri ;)

Comment: @Cory Klein: The most voted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579421/often-used-seldom-defined-terms-lvalue) is correct for C (I guess) but C++ is different. For instance, see the answer by [Johannes Schaub - litb](http://stackoverflow.com/a/579514/1137388). In particular he says "The term "rvalue" is used for things like literals and enumerator values and for **temporaries**".

Comment: @Cory Klein: Last comment: The C++11 standard says (3.10/1): "An **rvalue** (so called, historically, because rvalues could appear on the right-hand side of an assignment expression) is an xvalue, a **temporary object** (12.2) or subobject thereof, or a value that is not associated with an object.".

Comment: @CassioNeri Thanks for the link. I agree it makes a good argument for it being an r-value. I updated my answer, but now I'm just not really convinced either way, and I can't find anything more official than opinions of smart people on the internet.

Comment: @CassioNeri Ah! Perfect, just what I was looking for. I'll update the answer.